# Let z != -1, which module is 1. Prove that z is presentable z = (1+ti)/(1-ti), where t is real number

Tags: complex-numbers

Let z != 1, which module is 1. Prove that **z** is presentable in the following form:
$$ z =\begin{align}
\frac{1 + ti}{1 - ti}
\end{align}$$
 where t is a real number

So, im guessing i have to  multiply$$\begin{align}
\frac{1 + ti}{1 - ti} with: 1-ti
\end{align}$$

to get

$$ z =\begin{align}
\frac{1^2 - t^2i^2}{(1 - ti)^2}
\end{align}$$

and i also know that $$  i = \sqrt{-1} \begin{align}
\
\end{align}$$

But what about the t? How can i find it?

Comment: Hint: The triangle with vertices $1$, $z$, $-1$ has a right angle at $z$. (And the hypothesis is $z\ne-1$, not $z\ne1$.)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$|1\pm ti|=\sqrt{1+t^2}$$
hence
$$\left|\frac{1+ti}{1-ti}\right|=1$$
Now we should verify that the map
$$\Bbb R\rightarrow\{z\in\Bbb C\;|\; |z|=1\},\quad t\mapsto \frac{1+ti}{1-ti}$$
is surjective, in fact
$$\frac{1+ti}{1-ti}=\frac1{1+t^2}\left(1-t^2+2it\right)=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$
with
$$\cos\theta=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\;;\; \sin\theta=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\iff t=\tan\left(\frac\theta2\right)$$